# How to check if my manual is POSIX compliant?

Tags: man, posix

How to check if my man pages are up to date with POSIX?

Example: if I will type "man 3p xyz", I want to be sure, that if xyz exists in POSIX, I will get up-to-date information about this function and when it does not exists, I will get no information.

Comment: What manual? Are you writing the code and the manual yourself and want to make sure the format of the manual complies with POSIX or are you looking at a manual and wondering if it describes a POSIX-compliant application? Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: Is it clear yet?

Comment: So you want the man pages on your system to give information not about the `xyz` actually on your system but instead to show the manual of the most recent POSIX compliant version?

Comment: That doesn't make much sense. The `man` command is designed to provide manual pages matching what is currently installed on your machine. If your machine doesn't comply with the latest POSIX version, you want to upgrade it to that version and the manual pages will follow, not to only install discrepant manual pages.

Answer (score 3):

POSIX standardize commands, syntax, APIs and many other things, but not manual pages. There is then no way for a manual to be POSIX compliant (or not).

Note that the latest POSIX manual pages are available on line [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/).